# How to optimize the running speed of nested loops in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, nested, vectorization

I need to process elements of a four-dimensional matrix in matlab. Where `N` is around 100. The program below is very time consuming to calculate, I wonder if there is a suitable way to simplify it somewhat?

```
for i1 = 1 : N 
    for j1 = 1 : N 

        t1 = conj(PF(i1, j1));

        if abs(t1) ~= 0
            for i2 = 1 : N 
                for j2 = 1 : N 
                
                    t2 = PF(i2, j2);
                    mumual_intensity(i2, j2, i1, j1) = 
mumual_intensity(i2, j2, i1, j1) * t1 * t2;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

I understand that it is possible to modify index gridding to vector calculations, but I have not been able to successfully implement this myself.

Comment: It might be worth moving the i2 control loop to the outside so that cache locality is improved - or alternately swap i & j around so that j1, j2 loops are external and constant fiddle factor is applied many times in the inner loops over i1, i2. One or other rearrangement should be a distinct improvement.  Loop ordering will matter on such a big matrix structure.

Comment: Is `PF` an array or a function? If it’s a function, please post the code. Multiplication is in principle trivial to vectorize. — Ordering of loops is very important here, make the inner loop be the first index, and the outer loop the last index.

Comment: @CrisLuengo There PF is a N*N two-dimensional matrix. Its value has been given directly

Comment: Please [edit] your question to turn your code into a [mcve] which we can run and benchmark, otherwise suggestions are potentially too speculative to be helpful

Comment: Assuming, `PF` is a 2d matrix with fitting dimensions, it should be possible to replace the inner two loops with `mumual_intensity(:, :, i1, j1) = mumual_intensity(:, :, i1, j1) .* (t1*PF);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you should always order loops so that the first array dimension changes fastest (i.e. is the inner loop). This is how data is stored in memory, and accessing data in memory order makes best use of the cache. So reordering your loops as follows should significantly speed up your code:

```matlab
for j1 = 1 : N  % last dimension is outer loop
    for i1 = 1 : N  % second to last dimension

        t1 = conj(PF(i1, j1));

        if abs(t1) ~= 0
            for j2 = 1 : N  % second dimension
                for i2 = 1 : N  % first dimension is inner loop
                
                    t2 = PF(i2, j2);
                    mumual_intensity(i2, j2, i1, j1) = mumual_intensity(i2, j2, i1, j1) * t1 * t2;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Assuming `PF` is an array, we can vectorize the multiplication easily. `.*` is the element-wise multiplication. `mumual_intensity .* PF` will automatically expand `t2` to the same size as `mumual_intensity` by adding two dimensions at the end and replicating data along those dimensions. That is, each `mumual_intensity(i2, j2, :, :)` will be multiplied by `PF(i2, j2)`.

For the other multiplication (by `t1`), we must first add two dimensions at the start, which we can do with `shiftdim(PF,-2)`. Thus, the loop can be replaced by:

```matlab
mumual_intensity = mumual_intensity .* conj(shiftdim(PF,-2)) .* PF;
```

On my M1 Mac with MATLAB R2023b, with `N=100` and random double arrays, I see ~0.3s for the original code, ~0.2s with reordered loops, and ~0.08s for the vectorized code. The differences are not very big, but for sufficiently large `N` any gain is good.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It is very helpful and inspiring to me.

Comment: I accidentally discovered that the modification method of vectorization seems to cause some data loss. I checked the image by setting `i1=i2`, `j1=j2`, and found that compared to the original code, the vectorized writing method lacked edge data. I am not sure why this is?

Comment: This is the code I use to display the image.                                         
`pupil_image_intensity = zeros(N, N);
for i = 1 : N 
    for j = 1 : N 
        pupil_image_intensity(i, j) = real(mumual_intensity(i, j, i, j));
    end
end`

Comment: @Alex I verified that the one line of code I suggested here produces the exact same result as that code you posted in the question. There certainly isn’t going to be any differences at the edges. That must be caused by something else you’re doing.

Comment: OK, thank you for your reply. I think I need to examine it carefully.